# Which ffmpeg command sequence can generate the first frame of the video [Need thumbnails for Node.js app]

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I'm trying to make thumbnails for videos, but the problem is I'm not able to write some right ffmpeg commands for getting the very first frame. This is for a Node.js AWS Lambda function.

I tried this, but it's not working for me.

```
-vf "select=eq(n\,0)"
```

Tried all from here [How to extract the 1st frame and restore as an image with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425413/how-to-extract-the-1st-frame-and-restore-as-an-image-with-ffmpeg).

Here's my command line, I copied it and honestly I have no idea about this commands.

```
function createImage(type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let tmpFile = fs.createWriteStream(`/tmp/screenshot.${type}`);
      const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
      '-ss',
      '00:00:00.01',
      '-i',
      target,
      '-vf',
      `thumbnail`,
      '-qscale:v',
      '2',
      '-frames:v',
      '1',
      '-f',
      'image2',
      '-c:v',
      'mjpeg',
      'pipe:1',
    ]);


  ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(tmpFile);

  ffmpeg.on('close', function(code) {
    tmpFile.end();
    resolve();
  });

  ffmpeg.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    reject();
  });
});
}
```

(I use this https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ release 4.2.3 version on a Node child process.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the result you wanted.

You had some extra arguments in your command. You **should** read the [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) documentation.

```
function createImage(type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let tmpFile = fs.createWriteStream(`./screenshot.${type}`);
        const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
            '-i', target,
            '-r', '1',
            '-vframes', '1',
            '-f', 'image2',
            '-qscale:v', '2',
            '-c:v', 'mjpeg',
            'pipe:1'
        ]);


        ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(tmpFile);

        ffmpeg.on('close', code => {
            tmpFile.end();
            resolve();
        });

        ffmpeg.on('error', err => {
            console.log(err);
            reject();
        });
    });
}


createImage("jpg");
```